# How to select the current row?

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic, libreoffice-macros

How to select current row in calc of Libreoffice? use macro.

The effect I want to achieve is:
If the current row is an odd line,
Change the current row background color to blue.

```
If currentAddress.Row mod 2 = 1 Then
    dim document   as object
    dim dispatcher as object
    document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
    dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

    dim args1(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
    args1(0).Name = "ToPoint"
    args1(0).Value = "$A$3:$H$3"

    dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:GoToCell", "", 0, args1())

    dim args2(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
    args2(0).Name = "BackgroundColor"
    args2(0).Value = 17798

    dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:BackgroundColor", "", 0, args2())
End If
```

args1(0).Value = "$A$3:$H$3" ,

"$A$3:$H$3" . How to represent it as a range with variables?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that you are not actually looking for a conditional format that creates alternating formatting?

Answer (score 0):

> The effect I want to achieve is: If the current row is an odd line, Change the current row background color to blue.

Select all,  Format > Conditional Formatting > Condition... > Condition 1, Formula is,

```
ISODD(ROW())
```

New Style... > Background, select blue, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Alternative: [Autoformat](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/9205/is-there-a-way-to-add-background-color-to-alternate-rows-of-a-tablespreadsheet/).

Answer (score 0):

Select a cell and run this code

```
sub main
    Doc=thiscomponent
    Sheet=Doc.currentcontroller.activesheet
    ActiveCell = Doc.CurrentSelection 
    r = ActiveCell.CellAddress.Row
    if r mod 2 = 1 Then
        Sheet.getRows().getByIndex(r).cellBackColor = RGB(173,216,230) 
    end if   
end sub
```